# provide API or mock version based on runtime flag

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to provide either a mock or real implementation of an API interface based on a runtime flag. Here's my current approach:

```
providers:[{
  provide: MyApi,
  useFactory: () => {
     return env.useSpoofData ? mockMyApi : MyApi
  }
}]
```

I have defined `mockMyApi` as:

```
export const mockMyApi: MyApi = {
  get(): Observable<MyResponse> {
    const resp: MyResponse = {items};
    return observableOf(resp);
  },
};
```

The mock version of this works, but the real version, when provided this way, does not work. (the real version works if I don't do this provider overriding at all, however)

I have tried two ways to resolve the symbol for the "real" implementation.

One:

```
provide: MyApi,
deps: [MyApi],
useFactory: (real: MyApi) => env.spoof ? mockMyApi : real;
```

Fails. Cyclic dependency at build time.

Two:

```
provide: MyApi,
deps: [Injector],
useFactory: (inj: Injector) => env.spoof ? mockMyApi : inj.get(MyApi);
```

Fails. stack overflow at run time.

What's the correct way to instantiate or provide a class when returning it from a useFactory? Or, is there a simpler way to do provider overriding?

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/dependency-injection-and-providers/providers/#_usefactory

Comment: @SiddAjmera -- this is the "re-wrap" approach, where a new Provider "WrappedMyApi" provides one or the other based on runtime flag. Is this the only way to do this, as far as you know? I have no reason to change the original API name.

Answer (score 1):

You provide a factory, so you cannot simply pass the injection token as a factory result. `mockMyApi` is a constant while `MyApi` is a class. So, you need to create an object of that class. This is what factories are normally used for. Use `deps` to pass dependencies, e.g. `HttpClient`:

```
providers:[{
  provide: MyApi,
  useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => {
     return env.useSpoofData ? mockMyApi : new MyApi(/* args, e.g. http */)
  },
  deps: [HttpClient]
}]
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought the DI system would resolve the symbol for me. In any case, I've tried two ways to resolve to an instance, and they've both infinite looped (edited question above to include)

Comment: Your both ways are really funny. You cannot say, hey, DI, here is a provider I want to override, now, give me the service based on a provider I'm overriding. Of course it is infinite loop. You **must** create your object for DI on your own, and this is explicitly shown in my answer.

Comment: I can't manually create my DI instance, I'd like the system to resolve all the possible dependencies and to manage the singleton for me, as it would normally.

Comment: *I can't manually create my DI instance* - ??? Why? I got what you want but the world is not ideal. You don't want the default provider but you want the default provider. Just read this.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can find is to create a new "wrapped" API. Then, change all the consumers to point to the new `MyApiWrapped`. In your new implementation:

```
provide: MyApiWrapped,
deps: [Injector],
useFactory: (inj: Injector) => env.spoof ? mockMyApi : inj.get(MyApi);
```

This way, you can provide either implementation without causing a circular dependency. Additionally, the use of Injector here means you're allowing Angular to manage the cached singleton instance of your service and stand it up with the correct dependencies.